# How to pass csv file content to Http Call in Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

In DotNet code I read a csv file content convert that content in a single string and pass on to HttpRequestMessage as content. This call is success.

I want the exact same to be achieved in Azure Logic Apps. What flow item I should use to achieve this?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your csv file is on Blob Storage, you could just use Blob Connector to get the file content with action `Get blob content`. Just specify the blob you want to get.

[image]

Here is my csv content:

[image]

And this is the OUTPUT of logic app:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Can you provide more information? is it FTP, Onedrive etc?
- how are you going to pickup the       file? based on that use it's
  triggerbody.
- Use the content of the       shape pass that as an input    parameter
  along with the string       expression to make it as a    string and
  then pass it to the Azure       Function.
- if you can    specify the    trigger action or pick up system we
  can help you with    more    precise answer.

Comment: we will upload the file on blob storage